# What does it mean when a computer is 'greyed out' in Apple Remote Desktop?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I've got several computers that I manage using Apple Remote Desktop. Sometimes I have issues connecting with some of them. I've noticed this most often happens when their computer icon is light purple (greyed out) as opposed to dark purple.

Any ideas what this light purple means?

[image: screen shot from apple remote desktop]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [ARD Administrators Guide (PDF)](https://www.apple.com/server/docs/ARD3.2_AdminGuide.pdf), A "light purple" client status icon means that the client is offline (page 177).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @allan , its strange as the particular use i was trying to connect to was light purple, but they were on their machine, i couldnt connect so ended up walking over to their desk and working on the machine

Comment: It should be clarified that "offline" from ARD's perspective means the target isn't responding which could be due to any number of reasons (network, sleeping Mac, etc.), not powered off.    Make sure the clients have "remote management" enabled as well.